# How old are CSS filters?

Tags: css, filter

Filters like

```
img {filter:flipV;}
```

I'm guessing are pretty old, I just was asked by a colleague why they weren't working for him in FF. I assume they were an IE only thing that died out a while back?

Comment: Note that there's a working draft for official CSS support of *some* of this: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/

Browser support exists, but is still somewhat experimental.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen these transforms and transitions, I actually use an opcaity transition on my site targeted at Chrome. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were the only way to do some things in IE, for example PNG transparency in IE6...so they're still around.  Web developers everywhere are hoping they die :)

Even in the latest jQuery UI files you can find it being used for Alpha transparency: http://dev.jqueryui.com/browser/trunk/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css

By no means are they gone...unfortunately.  At this point, I'm hoping they don't stick something like this into IE9 and call it a "feature"...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is IE-only. They didn't die-out, they were just a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: I found out the hard way that there is a 4096-pixel limit on filters. If you apply them on anything larger (i.e. a modal screen overlay), they fail.

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty old and **work only in IE**. Bad, *don't use them* unless you are targetting only IE (not good again). There are some things in CSS3 not supported by IE, you can sometimes use these filters to get around things.

For example, **box shadow effect** can be easily done with CSS3 but IE again does not support that, you can use these **filters** for IE and **normal CSS3** for other browsers to create a **cross-browser** solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp) interesting. While `filter` is IE only, there is a Firefox equivalent (`opacity`) which is part of the CSS3 recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this article :)

Comment: Correction: it's the equivalent for the *Alpha* filter only, `filter:` has a lot of other types, see here for a quick rundown: http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/visual-filters.shtml

Comment: Note that the opacity in FF is ONLY equivalent to ONE specific filter, namely the alpha filter.  The filter functionality in IE is alot more than just opacity.

Edit: Nick beat me to it :-)